# Solving a radical equation

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, radicals

I have below radical equation which I need to solve for $x$. All other terms, $a,b,c$ are constants. BTW, $x$ is a real positive value.

$$\frac{(x+b)}{\sqrt{(x+b)^2+a^2}}  - \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}} = c$$

Any help / suggestion to solve this will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: If $|c|\gt 2$ there is no solution. So do we know more about the parameters $a$, $ b$ and $c$ ?

Comment: $c$ =0.0625. $a,b$ are real positive numbers. Thank you!

Comment: I am not behind my desktop and using my smartphone. So I cannot write details. Think geometrically. We have a difference of cosines of angles of two triangles who share one side namely $a$ and whose other side of the right angle differ by $b$

Comment: Yes. Actually I wrote down this equation based on difference of cosines. $x, b,a$ all are distance.

Comment: Could you please kindly elaborate more about your suggestion here. I think that makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried $\cos{x}-\cos{y}=2\sin{x+y\over2}\sin{x-y\over2}$

Comment: Not exactly. My equation is, $\cos x-\cos y=0.0625$. Let me try as you have suggested.

Comment: If you enjoy nightmares, you could square a couple of times and arrive to a polynomial in $x^8$ !

Comment: I already tried that and gave up :)

Comment: @marwalix: Could you please elaborate your suggestion further. I can write down following trig. equations based on geometry: $\cos x - \cos y = 0.0625$ and $\frac{a}{\tan y}+b = \frac{a}{\tan x}$

Comment: Still in my car. Try the trigonometric identity with $\cos{p}={x+b\over\sqrt{(x+b)^2+a^2}}$ and $\cos{q}={x\over\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}$

Comment: So far no luck :( I am trying with trigonometric identities.

Comment: @Sanka `Actually I wrote down this equation based on difference of cosines. x,b,a all are distance` It might help if you posted more context. It is entirely possible that the actual problem has different simpler solutions than the equation you derived.

Comment: Thnx dxiv. Let me explain my actual problem. I have those two parallel lines. Vertical gap between two parallel lines is, $a$. Starting from a single point on the upper line, I measure $\alpha$ and $\beta$ angles ($\beta >\alpha$) towards two points in the bottom line. The separation between those two points is, $b$. My requirement is to calculate the horizontal distance, $x$ between angle measuring point in the upper line and closest point to that in the bottom line,  when $cos \alpha - cos \beta = 0.0625 $

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Turns out it reduces to a quartic, though that's not any prettier.

Comment: @Sanka Is this an engineering problem by any chance? That's fairly easy to do numerically, less so symbolically.

Comment: Yes it is an engineering problem! My idea is to have a closed form expression to identify $x$. $c = 0.0625$, but $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers lie as, $100 <=a <= 200$ and $20<=b<= 500$. Any suggestion to derive a closed form expression for $x$? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sanka The quartic *does* give you (the path to) a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) for $x$, but that's not necessarily practical. You may be better served by using any one of [numerical methods](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Numerical_Methods/Equation_Solving) for solving nonlinear equations.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you! I was thinking to have at least an approximated closed form expression so that by plugging $a$ and $b$, it is possible to directly solve for $x$. Do you think curve fitting is a good option in this regard. I can generate 3D curve with given $a$ and $b$ bounds. Please kindly let me know your idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first tried to make the sense of geometry of this problem as described by marwalix and tried to avoid the square root by sine or cosine relations but I failed.

However, I use the Mathematica program which will not give the answer for arbitrary value c. If I assigned c=0.0625, then the answer could be written as follows. 
$$
\left(\left\{x\to \text{Root}\left[1023.00000000000 \text{$\#$1}^8+4092.00000000000 \text{$\#$1}^7 b+\text{$\#$1}^6 \left(3068.00000000000
   a^2+6138.00000000000 b^2\right)+\text{$\#$1}^5 \left(9204.0000000000 a^2 b+4092.00000000000 b^3\right)+\text{$\#$1}^4 \left(3066.00000000000 a^4+10738.0000000000 a^2
   b^2+1023.00000000000 b^4\right)+\text{$\#$1}^3 \left(6132.00000000000 a^4 b+6136.00000000000 a^2 b^3\right)+\text{$\#$1}^2 \left(1020.00000000000 a^6-257034.000000000
   a^4 b^2+1534.00000000000 a^2 b^4\right)+\text{$\#$1} \left(1020.00000000000 a^6 b-260100.000000000 a^4 b^3\right)-a^8+510.000000000000 a^6 b^2-65025.0000000000 a^4
   b^4\&,1\right]\right\}\right)
$$
Solve the $\#1$, for specific value of $a$ and $b$, the Root could be solved.

I think there could be better way to avoid this.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is interesting. Could you please let me know what is meant by #1 here? Also what is the meaning of 1 just before the square bracket? Please let me know.

Comment: I should have told you that "#1" is the root of equation, which in fact  is "x" here. The "&,1" is the first root of the equation, which is one of the 8 roots the equation has. The square bracket "]" comes from Root["]". The "}" comes from the first line { before $x$.

Answer (score 1):

The following reduces the equation to a quartic. Let $b=2 a d, x = a(y - d)$, then:

$$\frac{y+d}{\sqrt{(y+d)^2 + 1}} -  \frac{y-d}{\sqrt{(y-d)^2 + 1}} = c$$

Squaring:

$$\frac{(y+d)^2}{(y+d)^2 + 1} + \frac{(y-d)^2}{(y-d)^2 + 1} - 2 \;\frac{y^2-d^2}{\sqrt{(y+d)^2 + 1}\sqrt{(y-d)^2 + 1}} = c^2$$

Eliminating denominators:

$$(y+d)^2\big((y-d)^2 + 1\big) + (y-d)^2\big((y+d)^2 + 1\big) -c^2 \big((y+d)^2 + 1\big) \big((y-d)^2 + 1\big)
= 2 (y^2-d^2)\sqrt{\big((y+d)^2 + 1\big)\big((y-d)^2 + 1\big)}$$

Collecting and rearranging:

$$(2-c^2)(y^2-d^2)^2 + 2(1-c^2)(y^2+d^2) -c^2 = 2(y^2-d^2)\sqrt{(y^2-d^2)^2 + 2(y^2+d^2)+1}$$

Squaring again gives a quartic in $z = y^2$, which then could technically be solved in radicals.

Comment: Great! Thank you. Let me try to solve this.